# Rails 4.1.0 undefined method `call' for after upgrading from rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Hi I've upgraded from rails 4.0.0 to Rails 4.1.0

now I got this error:

[image]

when I delete

```
.active
```

it works ... but why? and how can I Fix this?

course.rb

```
  self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients, :join_table => :clients_courses  # TODO c
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships

  has_many :lessons,
        -> {order "lessons.sort ASC, lessons.start_date"},
        :dependent => :destroy,
        :foreign_key => :course_object_id

  scope :active, where(:active => true)
  scope :inactive, where(:active => false)
```

Comment: Well, do you have a method `active`?

Comment: Show us `app/models/course.rb` please.

Comment: I've added course.rb above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Change you course.rb code to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html):

```
  scope :active, -> { where(:active => true) }
  scope :inactive, -> { where(:active => false) }
```

Answer (score 2):

[You should provide lambda to the scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) in your `course.rb`:

```
scope :active, -> { where active: true }
scope :inactive, -> { where active: false }
```